# String interpolation of hashtable values in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I've got a hashtable:

```
$hash = @{ First = 'Al'; Last = 'Bundy' }
```

I know that I can do this:

```
Write-Host "Computer name is ${env:COMPUTERNAME}"
```

So I was hoping to do this:

```
Write-Host "Hello, ${hash.First} ${hash.Last}."
```

...but I get this:

```
Hello,  .
```

How do I reference hash table members in string interpolation?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
Write-Host "Hello, $($hash.First) $($hash.Last)."
```

Comment: Those extra `$` symbols are pretty ugly. I was hoping for something nicer.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe this is Powershell, it's not a pretty language, and string interpolation is especially nasty!

Answer (score 24):

```
"Hello, {0} {1}." -f $hash["First"] , $hash["Last"]
```

Comment: This requires extra brackets: Write-Host ( "Hello {0} {1}." -f ... )

Answer (score 3):

With the addition of a small function, you can be a bit more generic, if you wish. Watch out, though, you're executing potentially untrusted code in the `$template` string.

```
Function Format-String ($template) 
{
    # Set all unbound variables (@args) in the local context
    while (($key, $val, $args) = $args) { Set-Variable $key $val }
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
}

# Make sure to use single-quotes to avoid expansion before the call.
Write-Host (Format-String 'Hello, $First $Last' @hash)

# You have to escape embedded quotes, too, at least in PoSh v2
Write-Host (Format-String 'Hello, `"$First`" $Last' @hash)
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't get [Lemur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17033283/406859) to work in Powershell 4.0 so adapted as follows

```
Function Format-String ($template) 
{
  # Set all unbound variables (@args) in the local context
  while ($args)
  {
    ($key, $val, $args) = $args
    Set-Variable -Name $key.SubString(1,$key.Length-2) -Value $val
  }
  $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($template)
}
```